# Python(Spyder3, Win10) Write to Serial port more than once

Tags: python

I am trying to communicate with a microcontroller through a serial port.
For example, I write 7 to the microcontroller and I read a series of (47) numbers back, I then send 7 to it again and I read the same numbers back. I can keep going like this.
I have tried using Matlab and I can finish what I want to write and read from serial port very well. However, when I turn to use Spyder 3, under Win10, I can only write and read once. As I mentioned, if I write 7 and I can get 47 numbers back, but after that when I send 7 I can not get anything back and I need to re-plug serial port. My code is shown below. Thank you.

```
import serial
import time

"""Cmd definition"""
cmd_readreg = [7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
regNo = 47

""" setup serial """
with serial.Serial() as ser:
#ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.port = 'COM8'
    ser.bandrate = 19200

""" open serial """
ser.open()
if ser.is_open:
    print ("Device connected.")
else: 
    print ("Check device connection.")

""" send read register cmd to serial, cmd = 7 """
ser.write(cmd_readreg)
time.sleep(.1)
#print (ser.BYTESIZES)

""" read from serial"""
if ser.readable():
    reg1 = ser.read(size=regNo)
    print (reg1)
else:
    print ("no readable data")

""" send read register cmd to serial, cmd = 7 """
ser.write(cmd_readreg)
time.sleep(.1)
#print (ser.BYTESIZES)

""" read from serial"""
if ser.readable():
    reg2 = ser.read(size=regNo)
    print (reg2)
else:
    print ("no readable data")
```

Comment: Were you able to solve that issue? I am having the same problem using Python 3.6 with Spyder 4.